# How to manupulate {{#each something}} in the view ,where "something" is comming from database

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Actually I am new to meteor . I want to manupulate {{#each something}} in my view, without manipulating database. Is there something like i treat it like an array. actually  its returning the list of elements.

```
<select name="field">
  <option value="">Lists</option>
  {{#each something}}
    <option value="{{_id}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

JUST I WANT TO SHOW ALL THE ELEMENT within "options" except the LAST element.

Any Help would be appreciated .

Comment: Can you share how you are generating something atm so it's easier to edit?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show everything in "something" except the last thing, you can use @index in Blaze to detect when you're at the end. i'm using the each/in construct because i think it's easier to read.

```
<select name="field">
    <option value="">Lists</option>
    {{#each thing in something}}
        {{#if showThing @index}}
            <option value="{{thing._id}}">{{thing.name}}</option>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

for the JS, i'm making assumptions about how you get your data, but the helpers would look something like this:

```
Template.Foo.helpers({
    something() {
        return Somethings.find({});
    },

    showThing(index) {
        let somethingsCount = Somethings.find({}).count();

        return (index != (somethingsCount - 1));
    }
});
```